# Css display submenu on menu item hover

Tags: html, css

I have a menu where each menu item has a background image, when hovering over a menu item it is underlined by scrolling up the corresponding background image. Now I also want to display the submenu(with text items, no background image), but the submenu text isn't diplayed , if I set the border of the submenu I can see a rectangle with no proper content. I don't see what's wrong with the code, please help me correct (and improve) it.

//html structure

```
<div id="menu_top">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="home"><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#" class="menu">Menu</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                            <li>item1</li>
                            <li>item2</li>
                            <li>item3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="#" class="contact">Contacts</a></li>
                <li class="about"><a href="#" class="about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

//css styles

```
#menu_top
{
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../images/nav-bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  height: 150px;
      width: 815px;
}

ul#menu
{   
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   position: relative;
}

ul#menu li 
{
   background-position: left top;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   display: block;
   text-indent: -9000px;
   position: absolute;
   outline: none;
}

/*Menu items*/

// all menu items similar to this ...

ul#menu li.menu
{
   background-image: url(../images/nav-menu.png);
   height: 50px;
   width: 116px;
   top: 30px;
   left: 380px;
}


/* underline menu items*/
ul#menu li:hover
{
   background-position: left bottom;
}

#menu >li ul
{
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:50px;
   width:100%;
}

#menu >li ul>li
{
   list-style:none; 
}

#menu >li:hover > ul
{
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: Please http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/WJ876/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub menu items are not being displayed because you have set a `text-indent:-9000px` for `ul#menu li`, which means the text indent will apply to all the `li` items under the ul `#menu`. To display the sub menu items apply the below styles to the submenu li

```
#menu >li ul>li
{
   list-style:none;
   text-indent:0;
   position:relative; // this is set to remove position absolute set for ul#menu li
}
```

OR

```
#menu .submenu li{
    position:relative;
    text-indent:0;
}
```